# How to install wxWidgets via vcpkg on Visual Studio as automatically as possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets, vcpkg

reproduced steps:

- cloned vcpkg repo
- followed instructions from https://www.wxwidgets.org/blog/2019/01/wxwidgets-and-vcpkg/
- except: added vcpkg to path and then 'vcpkg integrate install' inside visual studio terminal

At [example](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_helloworld.html) file, it gives me three errors:

- __w64 can only be specified on int, long, and pointer types  Example01   C:\Users\Petre\source\repos\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\types.h
- LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
- LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: you mean you didn't do steps 4 and 5 or just step 5? You absolutely have to - nobody but you knows where `YOU` installed wxWidgets. Please follow instructions as they are written.

Comment: I cloned the vcpkg like another repo, my mistake was that instead of typing 'vcpkg integrate install' inside the vcpkg folder, I've typed that inside the project folder. 
I followed instructions and now I have 6 unresolved externals :(

Comment: please try to build and run `minimal` sample provided with the library. It already has the solution for MSVC, so you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: The `__w64` error is a IntelliSense error and can be safely ignored. That being said, cloning `vcpkg` and running `vcpkg integrate install` is sufficient to start using wxWidgets via Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to build a console subsystem project (with an entry point `main`), rather than a Windows project (`WinMain`). You need to change this in the linker options.

The `_w64` warning is a separate problem, but it should be a warning, not an error.